# How to change the appearance location of top menu in only home page magento

Tags: magento

I want to change the appearance location of top menu in only home page. The menus right now appear at the top after the logo image.

But I want to change them to appear any where else on home page only, on rest of pages the top menu should remain as it is now.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the home page's cms editor, tab "design", textarea "layout update xml", put:

```
<reference name="header">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/header_bis.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

changing the path to the template phtml file you wanna use.
HTH

Comment: You mean to say I have to create another header phtml file?

Comment: But I want the nav menu inside the home page content itself

Answer (score 0):

The CMS page for your homepage can be given its own theme/design settings.

Make a new theme with the navigation blocks that you need to change, XML and .phtml files that need the changes, not everything in the system.

Set your homepage to use the new theme, it should default to the existing theme for pieces that it cannot find in the homepage theme files, e.g. the footer .phtml etc.